# SSRS Subscriptions And Relay Setup

Tags: reporting-services, office365, windows-server-2022

Good day,
I need advice on getting SSRS subscriptions working again at my clients

1. Scenario 1 - Client upgraded server from Server 2012 with SSRS 2012 to Server 2022 with SSRS 2019 - They use the relay function due to the issue with the Office 365
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/670006/try-to-sending-email-not-working-with-suscription.html

I have setup the new server with the relay but now it fails and gives me an MMC error every time
[Server Specs & Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0VTd.jpg)
[SSRS Subscription Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90M5b.jpg)

Please advice what else I can do regarding this error - I tried to do windows update and it did not work and could not find useful topics to fix this issue

2. Second scenario - client running windows 10 that is not support with windows relay also using office365 mail server - does not want to upgrade to new server or use an alternative mail server - but they want to use SSRS subscriptions - is there any way forward or alternative way to use SSRS subscriptions with windows 10 or will they need to make the change
   https://adamtheautomator.com/iis-smtp-relay/

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I would think this question is better suited to https://serverfault.com , StackOverflow  is for specific code/programming issues.

Comment: @AlanSchofield - Thank you will do - However I did manage to find an article to help assist with the issue - https://serverfault.com/questions/1088555/server-2022-smtp-server-issue